# E-mail sent with PHPMailer ignores CSS styles

Tags: php, smtp, phpmailer

I'm sending a simple e-mail with PHPMailer (SMTP). Here I have an issue with CSS formatting. In general things like color changing is working. But other things like changing font-size not works. The email client ignores my styles. I'm using Spark. But I don't think that the problem is the client. I receive also other HTML emails.

**This is my code:**

```
$email_body = "
    <html>
        <head>
            <style>
                span {
                font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
                font-size:12px;
                color:#FF0000;
                }
                h2 {font-size: 50px}
            </style>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div>
                Hi there,<br><br>
                this is just a test e-mail.
                <br><br>
                <h2 style='color: darkblue;font-size:50px'>This is a headline</h2><br><br>
                <span>This is just a text</span>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
    ";

try {
    //Server settings
    $mail->isSMTP();
    ..... 
    $mail->Port = 587;

    //Recipients
    $mail->setFrom('email@email.de', 'John Doe');
    $mail->addAddress('email@email.de', 'John Doe'); //Add a recipient
    $mail->addReplyTo('noreply@email.de', 'Information');
    $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';

    //Attachments
    $path = '../tempfiles/';
    $files = preg_grep('/^([^.])/', scandir($path));
    foreach ($files as $f) {
        if (in_array($f, $file_names_arr)) {
            $mail->addAttachment("../tempfiles/" . $f);
        }
    }

    //Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);
    $mail->Subject = 'Email Subject';
    $mail->Body = $email_body;
    $mail->AltBody = "Test";

    $mail->send();

    // Delete images afterwards
    $path = '../tempfiles/';
    $files = preg_grep('/^([^.])/', scandir($path));
    foreach ($files as $f) {
        if (in_array($f, $file_names_arr)) {
            if (is_file("../tempfiles/" . $f)) {
                unlink("../tempfiles/" . $f);
            }
        }
    }
    echo json_encode(1);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo json_encode(0);
}
```

All typography elements like h2,h3, p, span have the same font-size and I can't change it. What could be the issue here?

Comment: Mail-readers don't process `<style>`. You need to use inline styles.

Comment: The <style> was just an experiment. As you can see I also use inline styles.. :-)

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/using-css-in-html-emails-the-real-story/

Comment: In other words: I have no way to change the font size in e-mails?

Comment: Yes, it seems like it.

Comment: I solved it using this email template: https://github.com/leemunroe/responsive-html-email-template/blob/master/email.html ... and it works. Within I can change the font size as well...